# display sco unix 5.0.6 samba usage

Tags: samba, open-files, sco

Is there a command on sco unix which will show which files are being accessed by the samba process ?

Something like lsof in linux maybe, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`smbstatus -v`

Will list all connections and locked files.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can look up this sort of question in the [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html). It doesn't list anything for `lsof` under SCO. But you can download and compile `lsof` for SCO, like for just about every existing unix variant.

Comment: yea, i figured as much. There's no build enviroment on the machine and it's going to be painful to add one. Oh wells.